# Weird parameter in VB param ( , ) converting to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to re-write some very old VB codes into C#.
There is a function as follows:

```
Function function1 (ByVal sp As String, Optional ByVal param(,) As Object = Nothing) As DataSet
```

And there is a comment:

```
//<param name="param">Parameters to pass to stored procedure</param>.
```

Can anyone let me know how to re-write param(,) into C#? Thanks!

Comment: when I see documentation it should be `Optional ByVal ParamArray param() As Object = Nothing` which its equivalent in c# is `params object[] param = null`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when I am looking at the legacy system, there is a comma ',' in the middle of the bracket - param(,). The codes is copied and pasted here directly from the system which is still fully functioning.

Comment: Do not use `ParamArray` - method expect 2-dimensional array as optional parameter

Answer (score 3):

```
Function function1 (ByVal sp As String, Optional ByVal param(,) As Object = Nothing) As DataSet
End Function
```

converts to:

```
public DataSet function1(string sp, object[,] param = null)
{
}
```

http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Thanks! That's useful!

Answer (score 2):

In vb.net you can use `param` as name for variable. Because vb.net use `ParamArray` as keyword for optional array of parameters - which equivalent to `params` in C#.

So in your case method just expect 2-dimensional optional argument.
Which can be converted in C# as

```
public DataSet function1(string sp, object[,] param = null)
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio!  Good to know the difference.